# Joomla 2.5 plugin wont work

Tags: plugins, joomla

I'm beginner and I wanna write a simple plugin for my website but I have some problems.

When I trying to import my plugin through the div into the article

`<div id="locker-464" class="like-dl blue"> </div>`

I only get the css frame no js.

```
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');
$document = & JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root() . 'plugins/content/plugin/tmpl/css/style.css', 'text/css', null, array() );
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . 'plugins/content/plugin/tmpl/js/liketodownlad.js');
$document->addScript ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js");
$document->addScript ("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1");

class plgContentLiketoDownload extends JPlugin {

function plgContentLiketoDownload( &$subject, $params ) 
    {
        parent::__construct( $subject, $params );
    }

 function onContentPrepare($context, &$params)
 {
 global $mainframe;
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $plugin = & JPluginHelper::getPlugin('content', 'plugin');
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();
            $jx(document).ready(function(){        

                $jx('#locker-464').liketodl({
                download_url: 'http://website.com/sampleDownload.zip',
                like_url: 'https://www.facebook.com/FBpage',
                like_colorscheme: 'light'
                });

                $jx('#locker-564').liketodl({
                download_url: 'sampleDownload.zip',
                like_url: 'http://google.com',
                like_colorscheme: 'list'
                });

            });";
</script>";

    return true;
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors or your error log or console? Also, you can remove `global $mainframe;` and you don't need to use the `&` operators before `JFactory` and `JPlugin`. Also, are you sure you want to be using a plugin? You might want to consider a module for what you're trying to do, which can easily be embeded in an article using `{loadposition xxx}`

Comment: I dont get any errors but module wont work anyway. I cant see javascript on my website. And it must be a plugin. thx

Comment: Just a thought are you running this from a content plugin rather than from for example a system plugin. At the top of your XML file do you have group="content".

Answer (score 0):

The onContentPrepare method signature is:

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
{
... your stuff
}
```

If you are replacing content of an article, assigning to $row->text will alter the output. Check /plugins/content/pagebreak/pagebreak.php for an example.

If you are using PHP 5.x don't use plgContentLikeToDownload as your constructor:

```
public function __construct(& $subject, $config)
{
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
        $this->loadLanguage(); // if needed
}
```

See http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

EDIT

---

Remove all the code outside the class declaration and try this:

```
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');
class plgContentLiketoDownload extends JPlugin {

    function plgContentLiketoDownload( &$subject, $params ) 
    {
        parent::__construct( $subject, $params );
    }

    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
       $row->text = "Hello world!";
       return true;
    }
}
```

END EDIT

Regards

Comment: I made this changes and still nothing. Any other clues? Thanks

Comment: Just to point some usual situations: is the plugin installed correctly? Is it published? As onContentPrepare is fired when displaying articles, are you showing some article?

Comment: Yes it is published, it always installs correcly. I trying to access plugin adding in article: '<div id="locker-464" class="like-dl blue"> </div>' but nothing happens.

Comment: There's a mistake on the last two lines of the code you post. The line  });"; should be }); because you terminate the echo on the next line.

Comment: I corected this mistake yesterday and nothing happened. I cant se the js in the code of my website. Maybe its that. I tried with $document->addScriptDeclaration(' '); and still nothing :/

Comment: Check the path of your installed plugin. It should be /plugins/content/liketodownload/liketodownload.php Also check the plugin name on the plugin manifest (install.xml).

Comment: Everything is as it should be.

Comment: Still nothing. I really dont know what can be an issue. I think I checked everything.